# Duqu and other reference material for security people

Tags: malware, antimalware

I would like to read more on Duqu and similar exploits when they appear. The problem is that most references from google are for laymen.
Isn't there a reference website or... that reports on these exploits with words adequate to security experts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This site may be what you are looking for:

http://www.nsslabs.com/blog/2011/11/duqu-analysis-and-detection-tool.html

It answers all the major questions I have short of looking at the code myself.

Answer (score 5):

For Duqu Symantic has a quite detailed explanation http://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/media/security_response/whitepapers/w32_duqu_the_precursor_to_the_next_stuxnet.pdf

Most anti-virus companies have some reporting on threats of varing levels of details. As this is not my specialty it appears to be random as to who will have details of what, but with a little hunting I can usually find something technical.

Comment: thx this.josh, but would there be a kind of blog like for instance the IT Security one where technical details can be retrieved?

Answer (score 5):

Symantec and the other anti-malware vendors have research team reporting on malware. They will be your best bet every time.

The reason the references from google are for laymen is that most security teams have a direct communication channel with their malware vendor, so only laymen would need to google (huge generalisation, I know, but from a commercial perspective this is the way it is)